# Spotify - Audio Feature exception

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I've been successufully retrieving `audio_features` from `Spotify`'s `recommendations` `endpoint`, like so.

```
features = sp.audio_features(tracks_ids)
```

However, if I provide a list of `id`'s retrieved using `search` `endpoint` and pass them in the exact same fashion to `sp.audio_features()`, I get this:

`spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 414, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features?ids=2ujuUDGDg6t5zsN6WZ3CFp,2EOThFm0IhwLkdpQzbvunO,40f9IDTMDpFf3CnTcPhY5F,78qoim2GGUkspkxV8kUtVv,4WZJ5W4gZJXvlqgliLkPCn,4mHS76nxzGrwo25KpzQwiX,1jRHh8JcdUV9zTiAmyzhU9...etc`

is there a different authentication flow? what is going on here?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a [414 status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15), which indicates that the requested URI is too long.

If you are providing 100 or less ids, then this is a bug on Spotify's end. In this case I would recommend you to file a ticket in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues) where they track issues with the Web API.

Comment: yes I did provide less than 100 ids, should be a bug and I've filed a ticket. thanks.